# Optirun fails on Ubuntu 17.10 with nvidia geforce 940MX

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I have a laptop with a dedicated nVidia Geforce 940MX GPU. I installed the bumblebee packages following the steps written in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee but whenever I want to run `optirun glxgears` it fails with the message

```
[  663.222353] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver

[  663.222380] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

I tried to follow the instructions in the `/etc/bumblebee/xorg.conf.nvidia` where it says to enter the correct BusID but the `lspci | egrep 'VGA|3D'` gives the following output

`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 179c (rev a2)`

which is the same BusID which is specified in the xorg.conf.nvidia file. I don't know how to fix this issue. In manjaro linux it worked flawlessly with the proprietary drivers but in Ubuntu it doesn't seem to work.

If anyone interested, here is my xorg.conf.nvidia file:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier  "Layout0"
    Option      "AutoAddDevices" "false"
    Option      "AutoAddGPU" "false"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier  "DiscreteNvidia"
    Driver      "nvidia"
    VendorName  "NVIDIA Corporation"

#   If the X server does not automatically detect your VGA device,
#   you can manually set it here.
#   To get the BusID prop, run `lspci | egrep 'VGA|3D'` and input the data
#   as you see in the commented example.
#   This Setting may be needed in some platforms with more than one
#   nvidia card, which may confuse the proprietary driver (e.g.,
#   trying to take ownership of the wrong device). Also needed on Ubuntu 13.04.
    BusID "PCI:01:00:0"

#   Setting ProbeAllGpus to false prevents the new proprietary driver
#   instance spawned to try to control the integrated graphics card,
#   which is already being managed outside bumblebee.
#   This option doesn't hurt and it is required on platforms running
#   more than one nvidia graphics card with the proprietary driver.
#   (E.g. Macbook Pro pre-2010 with nVidia 9400M + 9600M GT).
#   If this option is not set, the new Xorg may blacken the screen and
#   render it unusable (unless you have some way to run killall Xorg).
    Option "ProbeAllGpus" "false"

    Option "NoLogo" "true"
    Option "UseEDID" "false"
    Option "UseDisplayDevice" "none"
EndSection
```